# Calling xiCam.OpenDevice() for ximea camera raises exception "invalid handle"

Tags: c#

I'm trying to control a Ximea camera (http://www.ximea.com) via a C# application.

I used an example that the company ships with the camera. Everytime I want to connect to the camera (using the `OpenDevice` function), I get an error that says - 'invalid handle'. What does this mean and what can I do to fix that?

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing;
using xiApi.NET;
namespace xiApi.NET_example
{
class Program
{
 static void Main(string[] args){
 {
  xiCam myCam = new xiCam();
  try
  {
  // Initialize first camera
  myCam.OpenDevice(0);

  // Set device exposure to 2 milliseconds
  int exposure_us = 2000;
  myCam.SetParam(PRM.EXPOSURE, exposure_us);

  // Set device gain to 5 decibels
  float gain_db = 5;
  myCam.SetParam(PRM.GAIN, gain_db);

  // Set image output format to monochrome 8 bit
  myCam.SetParam(PRM.IMAGE_DATA_FORMAT, IMG_FORMAT.MONO8);

  //Start acquisition
  myCam.StartAcquisition();

  // Capture images
  Bitmap myImage;
  int timeout = 1000;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    myCam.GetImage(out myImage, timeout );
    string fName = string.Format("image{0}.bmp", i);
    myImage.Save(fName);
  }
  // Stop acquisition
  myCam.StopAcquisition();
}

catch (System.ApplicationException appExc)
{
  // Show handled error
  Console.WriteLine(appExc.Message);
  System.Console.ReadLine();
  myCam.CloseDevice();
}

finally
{
  myCam.CloseDevice();
}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the camera works and the API is properly installed?  The code you posted has no error checking, so where does this error come from?  Is it a dialog box?  If so, it sounds like either the driver or the library.

Comment: Did you step through this code with the debugger? If you are using Visual Studio, use `F10`. On which line does the error occur?

Comment: Are you sure it's device 0 and not 1?  When I design handles I usually reserve 0 for NULL.

Comment: I think that the API is properly installed because the program is running ok and the library is not given any error. yes I use the debugger and in myCam.OpenDevice(0) line i get the error of invalid handle. I try to use 0 or 1 in the camera ID that should be there but nothing change.

Comment: Please create a support ticket in the XIMEA public tracker: http://www.ximea.com/support/wiki/allprod/Contact_Support where our support personnel will help you to solve this issue. Also please include the information about installed SW package version, camera model, and serial number. Thank you.